# LEFT JOIN Columns With WHERE Clause in Oracle Entity Attribute Value(EAV) Database Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a USERS table like this

**USERS**

```
user_id | username
1         tom
2         sam
```

I also have a USER_META table like this

**USER_META**

```
user_meta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
1              1         active     1
2              1         car        dodge
3              2         active     0
4              2         car        honda
```

My problem is that I need to select the meta_keys *active* and and *car* but only for users who have a value of 1 for *active* so my result set should be something like this

```
user_id | user_name | user_meta_id | meta_key | meta_value
1         tom         1              active     1
1         tom         2              car        dodge
```

I have tried a few things but I cannot get this type of result set. Here is what I thought might work

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN USER_META 
   ON USERS."user_id" = USER_META 
   AND (USER_META."meta_key" = 'active' OR USER_META."meta_key" = 'car') 
WHERE (USER_META."meta_key" = 'active' 
AND USER_META."meta_value" = 1)
```

the problem with this is that I get a result set that is missing the car meta_key/meta_value

```
user_id | user_name | user_meta_id | meta_key | meta_value
1         tom         1              active     1
```

How can I modify the query to get all of the meta information? thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, this sort of entity-attribute-value data model is generally a very poor idea.  You're basically re-implementing what a relational database gives you out of the box and queries get very unwieldy very quickly.  Generally, you'll need to join in the `USER_META` table N times in order to either get N attributes as columns or in order to have N predicates on your data.

On the data modeling front, future developers will generally be grateful if you avoid creating case-sensitive column names so that they don't have to double-quote every identifier every time.

Since you need two keys, you should be able to do something like this (I assume that `meta_value` is always stored as a character string even if it represents a numeric or boolean value)

```
SELECT usr."user_id",
       usr."user_name",
       meta."user_meta_id",
       meta."meta_key",
       meta."meta_value"
  FROM users usr
       JOIN user_meta meta ON (usr."user_id" = meta."user_id")
 WHERE meta."meta_key" in ('active', 'car')
   AND usr."user_id" IN (SELECT active."user_id"
                           FROM user_meta active
                          WHERE active."meta_key" = 'active'
                            AND active."meta_value" = '1' )
```

which returns the expected results for the data you posted

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with users as (
  2    select 1 "user_id", 'tom' "user_name" from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'sam' from dual
  4  ),
  5  user_meta as (
  6    select 1 "user_meta_id",
  7           1 "user_id",
  8           'active' "meta_key",
  9           '1' "meta_value" from dual union all
 10    select 2, 1, 'car', 'dodge' from dual union all
 11    select 3, 2, 'active', '0' from dual  union all
 12    select 4, 2, 'car', 'honda' from dual
 13  )
 14  SELECT usr."user_id",
 15         usr."user_name",
 16         meta."user_meta_id",
 17         meta."meta_key",
 18         meta."meta_value"
 19    FROM users usr
 20         JOIN user_meta meta ON (usr."user_id" = meta."user_id")
 21   WHERE meta."meta_key" in ('active', 'car')
 22     AND usr."user_id" IN (SELECT active."user_id"
 23                             FROM user_meta active
 24                            WHERE active."meta_key" = 'active'
 25*                             AND active."meta_value" = '1' )
SQL> /

   user_id use user_meta_id meta_k meta_
---------- --- ------------ ------ -----
         1 tom            1 active 1
         1 tom            2 car    dodge
```

Comment: thanks a ton for this, and yes I agree that this is probably not the best db design. The use of case sensitive columns is to make it play nicely with the Codeigniter PHP framework.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
    LEFT JOIN USER_META ON 
        (USERS."user_id" = USER_META.”user_id” 
         AND (USER_META."meta_key" in ('active', 'car') 
WHERE USERS."user_id" IN (select USER_META."user_id" from USER_META 
                          where USER_META."meta_key" = 'active' 
                          AND USER_META."meta_value" = 1
                         )
```

Comment: This is getting results even if active = 0. In this case there should be no results for that user.

Comment: @Mike Really? That's odd... Would you mind showing some data, so we can fine tune this? BTW. I changed the code to use `IN` but that's just as the same as using multiple `OR`.

Comment: It's because of this: `WHERE USERS."user_id" IN (select USERS."user_id" from USER_META` but it should be `WHERE USERS."user_id" IN (select USER_META."user_id" from USER_META`

Comment: @wweicker My mistake, now it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head since I do not have an Oracle instance to test with but something along these lines:

```
SELECT  T1.user_ID, T1.user_name, T2.user_meta_id, T2.meta_key, T2.meta_value
FROM    USERS T1 JOIN USER_META T2 ON T1.user_id = T2.user_id
        AND ((T2.meta_key = 'active' AND meta_value = 1) OR (T2.meta_key = 'car'))
```

Comment: Your query doesn't take in mind that user_meta_id has necessarily to have the 1 of active meta key

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT 
    um1.user_id, um1.user_name, um.user_meta_id, 
    um.meta_key, um.meta_value 
FROM 
    USER_META um, 
    (
        SELECT 
            um0.*, u0.user_name 
        FROM
            USER_META um0, USERS u0
        WHERE 
                u0.user_id = um0.user_id 
            and um0.meta_key = 'active' 
            and um0.meta_value= '1'
    ) um1
WHERE
    um.meta_key in ('active','car') 
    and um.user_id = um1.user_id
```